# Canvas clipping isn't smooth

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there a way to smooth the clipping mask paths in canvas? I'cant seem to find a solution online. It's quite smooth in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari. Here is the example code and a link to Codepen:

http://codepen.io/VincentPeters/pen/LNdZba?editors=0010

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var img;
var circleSize = 100;
var imageLoaded = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    //circles in percentage
    var circles = [
        [85, 75],
        [25, 65],
        [75, 40],
        [30, 30]
    ];

    var ctx = initCanvas();

    circles = calculateCirclePositions(ctx, circles);

    img.onload = function () {
        imageLoaded = true;
        drawCircles(ctx, circles);
        drawConnection(ctx, circles);
    };
});

function calculateCirclePositions(ctx, circles) {
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        circles[i][0] = (circles[i][0] / 100) * ctx.canvas.width;
        circles[i][1] = (circles[i][1] / 100) * ctx.canvas.height;
    }

    return circles;
}

function initCanvas() {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;

    ctx.canvas.width = 600;
    ctx.canvas.height = 600;

    img = new Image();
    imageLoaded = false;
    img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/jDp7UPB.jpg';

    return ctx;
}

function drawCircles(ctx, circles) {
    if (!imageLoaded) {
        return;
    }

    circles.forEach(function (entry) {
        drawCircle(ctx, entry[0], entry[1])
    });
}

function drawCircle(ctx, x, y) {
    if (!imageLoaded) {
        return;
    }

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, circleSize / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawConnection(ctx, circles) {
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length - 1; i++) {
        var V = [];
        var N = [];
        var R1 = [];
        var R2 = [];
        var R3 = [];
        var R4 = [];

        V[0] = circles[i + 1][0] - circles[i][0];
        V[1] = circles[i + 1][1] - circles[i][1];

        var length = Math.sqrt(V[1] * V[1] + -V[0] * -V[0]);

        N[0] = V[1] / length;
        N[1] = -V[0] / length;

        R1 = [
            circles[i][0] + N[0] * circleSize / 2,
            circles[i][1] + N[1] * circleSize / 2];

        R2 = [circles[i][0] - N[0] * circleSize / 2,
            circles[i][1] - N[1] * circleSize / 2];

        R3 = [circles[i + 1][0] + N[0] * circleSize / 2,
            circles[i + 1][1] + N[1] * circleSize / 2];

        R4 = [circles[i + 1][0] - N[0] * circleSize / 2,
            circles[i + 1][1] - N[1] * circleSize / 2];

        ctx.save();
        ctx.moveTo(R1[0], R1[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(R2[0], R2[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(R4[0], R4[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(R3[0], R3[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(R1[0], R1[1]);

        ctx.clip();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe someone will have a better solution and an explanation but it seems that using `globalCompositeOperation` and an offscreen canvas offers better results : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqaeGL?editors=0010

Comment: draw it twice as big and downscale together with @Kaiido 's solution :D

Answer (score 1):

You could make your canvas twice as big and scale it down. It will be less performant but the quality will be better.